# Showing a timer in a window while a Process is running

Tags: java, swing

So I'm currently executing a script through the following function:

```
public static boolean executePythonScriptWithArgs(File file, String args) {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 " + file.getPath() + " " + args);

                BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                // Read the output from the command
                String s;
                while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                    if(s.equals("success")) {
                        result = true;
                    }
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    executor.submit(r);

    return result;
}
```

In order to stop the GUI from freezing, I am creating a new `Runnable` object and executing this to check if the result is true. I am changing the variable result using the following:

`private static volatile boolean result = false;`

It is `volatile` to be able to change the value during the runnable thread.

However, this just runs in the background and I wish to open up a new window (maybe using `JOptionPane` if its possible to do it like this) to just show a timer, and then close it when the success value is reached.

How could I do this?

**EDIT:**

The code that I am using (aside from the JFrame to hold the panel) is shown below:

**MyListener.java**

```
public class MyListener implements ActionListener
{
    public static InputStream getScriptResource(String fileName) {
        ClassLoader classLoader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
        InputStream is = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("scripts/" + fileName);
        return is;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == MyPanel.button) {
            String options = "";

            try {
                File tempFile = File.createTempFile("quick", ".py");
                tempFile.deleteOnExit();
                // Get your script and prepare OutputStream to tempFile
                // Try with resources, to close streams
                try (InputStream is = getScriptResource("quick.py"); FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile)) {
                    // Copy InputStream to OutputStream.
                    IOUtils.copy(is, out);
                }
                boolean result = ScriptExecutor.executePythonScriptWithArgs(tempFile, options);
                if (result) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Client.INSTANCE, "Scan completed successfully!", "Info", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**MyPanel.java**

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    public static JButton button;
    private ActionListener myListener;

    public MyPanel() {
        this.myListener = new MyListener();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));

        addComponents();

        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void addComponents() {
        button = new JButton("Run Script");
        button.addActionListener(myListener);
        add(button);
    }
}
```

**ScriptExecutor.java**

```
public class ScriptExecutor
{
    private static volatile boolean result = false;

    public static boolean executePythonScriptWithArgs(File file, String args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 " + file.getPath() + " " + args);

                    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
                            InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

                    // Read the output from the command
                    String s;
                    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                        if(s.equals("success")) {
                            result = true;
                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        executor.submit(r);

        return result;
    }
}
```

This code can be put into any jframe to be run - **NOTE**: My environment uses Maven and the script would be found inside the resources folder.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html

Comment: You should use `new ProcessBuilder(List<String>)`. If your `args` or `file` contains space, then this won't work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way: declare your dialog window before the long running code, but display it *after* executing the thread. Then use a call-back to close the dialog after the thread has completed its run. The reason for the order given above -- the dialog needs to be visible to the call-back, hence needs to be declared first, but a modal dialog will block code flow, and so it needs to be displayed after starting the background thread.

Note that SwingWorkers have callback mechanisms already set up for you, and you can use this if desired.

For example:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class CallBackEgGui extends JPanel {
    private Action startThreadAction = new StartThreadAction(this);
    private JButton startThreadBtn = new JButton(startThreadAction);
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(15, 30);
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();

    public CallBackEgGui() {
        progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);

        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(startThreadBtn);

        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(scrollPane);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public void showText(String text) {
        textArea.append(text + "\n");
    }

    public void startProcess() {
        // disable the JButton
        startThreadAction.setEnabled(false);

        // display a JOptionPane (or any modal JDialog) that can hold anything, including a counter if we want
        // would use a Swing Timer if I wanted to show a Timer
        String title = "Running Python Script";
        int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CallBackEgGui.this, progressBar, title , messageType);
    }

    public void endProcess(boolean result) {
        // re-enable the JButton
        startThreadAction.setEnabled(true);

        // one way to close the JOptionPane
        Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(progressBar);
        win.dispose();

        // display another JOptionPane that shows the result of the process
        String message = "Python script Success: " + result;
        String title = "Return From Python Script";
        int messageType = JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(CallBackEgGui.this, message, title , messageType);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        CallBackEgGui mainPanel = new CallBackEgGui();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("LongRunningTimer");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }

}
```

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class StartThreadAction extends AbstractAction {
    private CallBackEgGui gui;
    private LongRunningCode longRunningCode;

    public StartThreadAction(CallBackEgGui gui) {
        super("Start Long Running Code");
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        longRunningCode = new LongRunningCode(gui);
        longRunningCode.execute(); // start the SwingWorker

        // order is important since the method below shows the modal dialog
        // and thus blocks any code flow below it. So execute the worker FIRST
        // before calling this blocking code
        gui.startProcess(); 
    }
}
```

```
class LongRunningCode extends SwingWorker<Boolean, String> {
    private static final int MAX = 10;
    private static final long MILLI_SECONDS_SLEEP = 400;
    private CallBackEgGui gui;

    public LongRunningCode(CallBackEgGui gui) {
        this.gui = gui;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
        // this code is in place of the Python script
        // done within a background thread
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(MILLI_SECONDS_SLEEP);

            // in the real program, the text will be from the InputStream from
            // the Python process.
            String text = "Value: " + i;  
            publish(text);  // then send the text to the GUI
        }

        // occasionally returns false
        boolean returnValue = Math.random() > 0.2;
        return returnValue;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
        // this code is called on the Swing event thread
        for (String text : chunks) {
            gui.showText(text); // tell GUI to display text
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // this code is called on the Swing event thread
        try {
            boolean result = get(); // get the result from the Worker thread
            gui.endProcess(result);  // tell GUI that process is done
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO handle exception!
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also check out [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to reach the callback to close it upon reaching the `success` result?

Comment: @madcrazydrumma: best if you could first create a valid [mcve] for us to work with and post it in your question. Since we answer as volunteers, better that such work be done by the asker first. You can use a `Thread.sleep` to simulate the long-running Python code.

Comment: Edited OP to include a gist - the code should run by adding it to a JFrame

Comment: @madcrazydrumma thanks for the link, but we don't do links here. All code should be posted in your question as code-formatted text. The goal of this site is to provide questions and answers that help all, not just the original poster, and so we require that the question be complete unto itself. Thanks for your understanding in this.

Comment: Sorry for the misconception of that :) The code is added to the OP

Comment: @madcrazydrumma: Better, but I'm asking a lot more from you, and sorry for this, but it's a process to learn how to best use this site, and if you use it in the future, this will help you. You'll want to create a new program, one that doesn't require files that we don't have, classes (IOUtils) that we don't have, that doesn't even require Python, a simple program that demonstrates the problem. I'm trying to create one myself, and if I can get it up without too much trouble I'll show you, but in the mean time, I ask you to do the same.

Comment: Your current code does not look to be Swing thread safe by the way

Comment: I looked around of how to execute the process and this is what was suggested.

Comment: I have no idea how to call Python, and I'm not criticizing that, but rather your direct use of Streams on the Swing event thread. Also, you're `executePythonScriptWithArgs(...)` method returns its boolean *immediately* before the thread has run, making the result meaningless. This definitely *requires* a callback, and I would again suggest that you use a SwingWorker for this, perhaps a `SwingWorker<Boolean, String>` to handle the returned boolean as well as the Strings created during the python run.

Comment: @madcrazydrumma: please see my example [mcve] program above. Please ask if any questions

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I managed to figure it out using `SwingWorker<Boolean, String>` as you suggested and calling the window before running the process and disposing of it after in the `done()` method!

Comment: @madcrazydrumma: good deal! Please also check out [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Also note that my code above can be copied and pasted into any IDE and run unchanged (for future references when asking questions on this site).

Comment: Thanks for the help, greatly appreciated.